# Installing new version of Android app on a previous device always reverts to the old version

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk, google-play-services

*I have seen similar questions to this, but without a full explanation and none with a sufficient answer.*

I am building my apps in Android Studio using the Generate Signed Bundle/APK option (I am building APKs, not bundles) and using the same key each time I build. I update both the versionCode and the versionName in build.gradle every time I update my apps (and I have examined the built Android Manifest to ensure that the versionCode does change). Note that I do not use the Google Play Store and I install these apps straight from the APK files.

Whenever I install the APK on a device that has never used that app, it installs correctly with the current version. But often, when installing a new version on a device that has previously used the app, it reverts back to an old version of the app.

I have tried everything I can think of: clearing all data from the app and reinstalling, turning off app sync, clearing play store and play services cache, resetting all app preferences, etc. and I have found absolutely nothing that works to fix this except for factory resetting the entire device.

This has become extremely frustrating and Google seems to pretend that this issue does not exist at all. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: More likely is that the app installation silently fails and thus the app remeins the same. Therefore always install APK files via adb so you will see if installation fails and also why it fails.

Comment: I have verified that the app installs successfully. And it only has this issue randomly on some devices that previously had the app installed.

Comment: If there are only problems when a previous version is installed then the APK signature is most likely not matching. You can only install an updated APK if the old APK and the new have the same signature.

Comment: I have stated in my answer that all of this holds true. The app installs successfully and it is guaranteed to use the same key as I use the same key for all of my apps. Even if I uninstall the entire application from the device, it comes back when installing the update, meaning that the device is storing the old version somewhere in storage.

Comment: Android don't cache apps/APKs. So if you uninstall the app it is gone (you can only uninstall an app but keep the data). The only way the old version could reappear is e.g. if it was automatically installed e.g. by Play Store (because that version is online the latest). Or your flash memory is near EOL and fails to write data.

Comment: I have been suspicious of Play Store being behind this since it started happening. The issue is that these apps are installed straight from the APKs and I do not use Play Store. Can Play Store somehow cache an old version of a manually installed app?

Comment: To my knowledge Play Shore does not cache apps. But be aware that Play Store can update apps that were not installed by it. So even side-loaded apps can be updated by Play Store if it is also available in Play Store. We had a question some month ago about an app that was installed via Galaxy or Amazon store but Play store had automatically updated but.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a VERY long time, I finally figured out the source of this problem. The cause of the issue has to do with the fact that I store my APKs on a website and users download the APKs from the site.

The issue I was having was not related to Android, the Play Store, or to Android Studio, but instead by the web browser caching the downloaded APK.

The solution was to simply make sure that each app update uses a different name for the APK file to stop the web browser from caching it.